# Somatic cell cloning always produces female offspring?

Tags: genetics, cloning

I was looking at the somatic cell cloning of goats.

One of the advantages of the process said was

- All offspring produced are female.

Now I'm confused. 
How is this the case?

I know that the embryo after electrofusion is injected into a surrogate mother, but I don't understand how the advantage is that they are "all ... female."

Comment: What is the sex of the somatic cell donor?

Comment: @AlanBoyd I don't know! That's what I was confused by.

Comment: Probably you should provide a link to your source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most species of livestock only the females are of economic value. And if you clone a female, you will only get female offspring.

I can also imagine that you would want to use an oocyte and somatic nucleus from the same animal. This way, you also preserve the mitochondrial DNA from your golden goat. And males just don't make eggcells.
It could also potentially avoid any incompatibilities between host and donor, somewhat comparable to donor organs. But I don't know if this is actually an issue.